# Offer user to install Mysql (NSIS)

Tags: mysql, installation, nsis

I'm trying to make installer for my program. It uses Mysql and I want to offer user to install it.  How can I do it by NSIS ?

Here my installing script

```
OutFile "setup.exe"

InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\MYApp\ 

Page directory
Page instfiles

Section ""
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR\MYApp
   File C:\ForSetup\*.*
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Do you want a checkbox on the components page, a custom page or just a simple MessageBox like you put in your answer?

Comment: @Anders, I want checkbox

Comment: Checkbox on the components page or a custom page?

Comment: @Anders, on the custom page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nsDialogs or InstallOptions to create custom pages:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include Sections.nsh

Page Custom MyPageCreate MyPageLeave
Page InstFiles

Section "Foo v1.2.3.4" SID_INSTALLFOO
MessageBox mb_ok "Installing Foo"
SectionEnd


Var MyCheckboxHandle

Function MyPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0 ; $0 is "error" if there was a problem

${NSD_CreateLabel} 10u 10u 100% 12u "Hello world, blah blah blah blah?"
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateCheckBox} 15u 30u 50% 12u "Install Foo v1.2.3.4"
Pop $MyCheckboxHandle
${NSD_Check} $MyCheckboxHandle

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageLeave
${NSD_GetState} $MyCheckboxHandle $0
${If} $0 <> 0
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${SID_INSTALLFOO}
${Else}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SID_INSTALLFOO}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Section ""
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR\MYApp
   File C:\ForSetup\*.*

 MessageBox MB_YESNO "Mysql is required. Do you want to install it ?" /SD IDYES IDNO endWork
    ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\msiExec" /i "mysql-installer-web-community-5.6.22.0.msi"'

     endWork:
     ; the end
SectionEnd
```